# Does JDBC driver for MongoDb exist?

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc

I am trying to add mongodb support for my little java project in which I used hibernate, mysql and postgresql. What library do I have to install?

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

This code above does not add mongo jdbc drivers as i am getting this error

```
    WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: mongo-java-driver is not a JDBC driver, just as mongodb is not an sql database.

Comment: If you want to use mongodb with hibernate, I think you should try hibernate ogm instead of hibernate orm

Comment: @Snoob does hibernate ogm support relational databases as well?

Answer (score 3):

There are more than a handful of MongoDB JDBC drivers out there, but most of them are proprietary and require some license fee, the one free and open-source jdbc driver for MongoDB I can find is from DbSchema, which is available here:

https://www.dbschema.com/mongodb-jdbc-driver.html

Source code is on bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/dbschema/mongodb-jdbc-driver/src/master/

It's completely free and works perfectly for me.

Comment: Source code now lives at GitHub: https://github.com/wise-coders/mongodb-jdbc-driver

Comment: Driver download now lives at: https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/MongoDb.html